# Converting a python dictionary into modified dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this :

```
[{'Custodian': a, 'BatchId': b, 'Key': c, 'BamSymbol': d, 'SecurityType': e, 'PMCode': f, 'ComplianceGroup': g, 'SubStrategy': h, 'AggregationUnit': i, 'Strategy': j, 'Size': k, 'Side': l}]
```

But i want to convert this dictionary as a modified one :

```
[{'Custodian': a, 'BatchId': b, 'Security': {'Key': c, 'BamSymbol': d, 'SecurityType': e}, 'Portfolio': {'PMCode': f, 'ComplianceGroup': g, 'SubStrategy': h, 'AggregationUnit': i, 'Strategy': j}, 'Size': k, 'Side': l}]
```

I am not sure how to proceed with this.

Comment: This is a list containing a dictionary with several sub-dictionaries. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I don't know how to proceed ! Since i am new to python i am trying out few things . Will post soon , Whatever i have tried.

Comment: You should find out how to access key-value pairs of dictionaries and how to generate new dictionaries as a starting point. And you should clarify if you really have to use a dict inside a list. If so, you should keep in mind to extract the dict from that list before accessing the dict.